# How to check the graph is 2-colorable or not?

Tags: c++, graph, bipartite, graph-coloring

I want to find whether the graph is 2-colorable or not more ie.  bipartite or non-bipartite.

Here is my code in C++ I'm using Welsh Powell Algorithm but something is wrong in the code may be I am missing some corner cases or some logical mistake.

Input  n=no. of vertex, m = no. of edges, 0 based indexing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


 pair <int,int> s[1001];
 int comp( pair <int,int> s1, pair <int,int> s2)
 {
     if(s1.first>s2.first)
        return 0;
     else
        return 1;
 }
int main()
{

        int n,i,j,k,flag=0;
        bool a[1001][1001]={false};
        int s1[1001]={0};
        int s3[1001]={0};
        for(i=0;i<1001;i++)
        {
            s[i].first=0;
            s[i].second=i;
            //s1[i]=0;
        }
        long long m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        while(m--)
        {
            int x,y;
            cin>>x>>y;
            if(x==y)
                continue;
            a[x][y]=true;
            a[y][x]=true;
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(a[i][j]==true )
            s[i].first++;

        sort(s,s+n,comp);
        int color=1,p=0,z,f;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            k = s[n-i-1].second;
            if(s1[k]==0)
            {
                s1[k]=color;
                p=0;
                    s3[p++]=k;
                    for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
                    {
                        f=0;
                        if(s1[s[j].second]==0)
                        {
                            for(z=0;z<p;z++)
                            {
                                if(a[s3[z]][s[j].second]==false || s3[z]==s[j].second)
                                    continue;
                                else
                                {
                                    f=1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(f==1)
                                continue;
                            else
                            {
                                s3[z]=s[j].second;
                                p++;
                                s1[s[j].second]=color;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                color++;
            }
            if(color==3)
                break;
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(s1[i]==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }

            if(flag==1)
            cout<<"NO\n";
            else
            cout<<"YES\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you know that it's wrong?

Comment: it's from a live contest so i cant discuss the question here.

Comment: How would you expect us to help you if you can't discuss it?

Comment: i want some to see is there any logical mistake in my code or is there any case where my code may fail or some special 2-coloring graph?
Once the contest will over i will post the original question

Answer (score 0):

To show that a graph is bipartite, you do not need a fancy algorithm to check. You can simply use a coloring DFS (Depth-First Search) function. It can be implemented as follows:

```
int color[100005];              //I assume this is the largest input size, initialise all values to -1.
vector<int> AdjList[100005];    //Store the neighbours of each vertex
bool flag = true;               //Bipartite or Not Bipartite

void dfs(int x, int p){         //Current vertex, Parent Vertex
    if (!flag) return;
    if (p == -1) color[x] = 0;
    else color[x] = 1 - color[p];
    for (int i = 0; i < AdjList[x].size(); ++i){      //For Every Neighbour
        int v = AdjList[x][i];                        //Vertex to be checked
        if (color[v] == color[x]){                    //Same color -> Not bipartite
            flag = false;
            return;
        }      
        if (color[v] == -1){                           //Unchecked
            dfs(v,x);                                  //color
        }              
    }
}
```

Comment: are u sure it covers all the cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Original Problem :  https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHFNFRN

@Benson Lin Thank You For Such Help.

Well the problem with your ans is it fails if the graph is disconnected i.e if it has for then 2 disconnected subgraph. 
As we are selecting source node at random the above code just check for that the subgraph with that node and gives the ans only for the subgraph not for the graph.
With small change in the above code we can solve this.

```
int colorArr[1001];

bool isBipartite(bool G[][1001], int src,int n)
{
colorArr[src] = 0;
queue <int> q;
q.push(src);
while (!q.empty())
{
    int u = q.front();
    q.pop();

     // Find all non-colored adjacent vertices
    for (int v = 0; v < n; ++v)
    {
        // An edge from u to v exists and destination v is not colored
        if (G[u][v]==true && colorArr[v] == -1)
        {
            // Assign alternate color to this adjacent v of u
            colorArr[v] = 1 - colorArr[u];
            q.push(v);
        }
         if(G[u][v]==true && colorArr[u]==colorArr[v] && u!=v)
                return false;

        //  An edge from u to v exists and destination v is colored with
        // same color as u
    }
}

// call the function with source node which is not color.
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{

        if(colorArr[i]==-1)
        {
            if(isBipartite(G,i,n))
            continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(G[i][j]==true )
        {
            if(colorArr[i]==colorArr[j] && colorArr[i]!=-1)
                return false;
        }

    }
}

return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

BFS can be used, by coloring the alternate levels with different colors and stopping if two nodes of the same color are found adjacent (not bipartite) or no such inconsistent coloring is found (bipartite). Here is the python code (*adj* being the adjacency list for the input graph to be checked):

```
def bipartite(adj):
    color = [None]*len(adj)
    for vertex in range(len(adj)):
        if not color[vertex]:
            queue = [vertex]
            color[vertex] = 'red'
            while len(queue) > 0:
                u = queue.pop(0)
                for v in adj[u]:
                    if color[v] ==  color[u]:
                        return 0
                    if not color[v]:
                        queue.append(v)
                        color[v] = 'red' if color[u] == 'blue' else 'blue'
    return 1
```

The following animation shows the output of a bfs run on a given input graph and a 2-coloring of the graph (the bfs queue is also shown).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the solution is first we create a color vector of zeros that represent the color of each vertex:
0: vertex not colored.
1: vertex is colored red.
2: vertex is colored blue.

Second: choose a random vertex (lets call it u) and color it by 1 which is red then apply depth first search on this vertex, where we go to all the adjacent vertices of our u (lets call them v) and color them with the opposite color which in our case is blue, each of those vertices can be:

node v is not colored: in this case we color it by opposite color to u.
node v is already colored:
1- same color as node u: so no problem.
2- opposite color to node u: then in this case node v must have been colored by other adjacent node to it (lets call it x) and it is opposite to node x in color, and it is impossible for node v to be opposite to both node x and u at the same time, which imply that this graph is not Bicolourable.

otherwise then the graph is Bicolourable

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> adjList;
vector<int> color;
bool bicolourable=true;

void dfs(int node, int c){
    if(color[node]==c)      return;
    if(color[node] != 0){
        bicolourable = false;
        return;
    }
    color[node]=c;  
    for(auto adjacent : adjList[node])
        dfs(adjacent, (color[node]==1 ? 2 : 1));
}

bool isBicolourable(){
    dfs(0, 1);
    return bicolourble;
}
```